# windows service cannot access a webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, system-administration

We have two servers, both are containing a local application connecting to local web service, applications and services are identical on both servers.

One of the servers work just fine,

The other one is just dead, I have impression the the security configuration are different on those servers.

What prevents an application X from connecting a web-service, given that another application y on the same server can connect to it. and X is a windows service.

What I should check, what is chances?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more info ? What error messages are you getting ? Can you show some code ?

Comment: This is the problem, simply connection failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is any firewall that might need to some ports opened up.

Could there be any kind of AntiVirus or similar set up on one of the servers?

Comment: Firewall I already add an exception, Anti-virus, why I should care?

Comment: Some AntiVirus includes blocks on outgoing traffic to stop unauthorised outgoing traffic. Most common is that they often stop outgoing traffic on port 25, but possibly some of them stop other traffic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basic troubleshooting of loosely-coupled applications means independent testing/verification of those services.

Can you access the web service locally through a different application, i.e. a web browser?  If you can't reach the service through the browser, then the server configurations (at some level) are not identical.

Only after you're certain the service is reachable should you look into issues with the windows service.

Comment: yes I access the web service through a web browser. furthermore I consume it with a third application!!! I recognize that the problem is related to the windows service or the EXE run by the win service.  What I should do about them, permissions, in which account they should run.